# IBM DB2 drop type error

Tags: db2

I have a DB2 Db with this

```
create type mycar as(<br/>
     description varchar(30)<br/>
)MODE DB2SQL;
```

how to delete that type?

I try drop type mycar, but have an error: DB2 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows: "DECLARE" was expected after ";".

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the ';' as command separator?

The Declare is just after the ';' which seems that your command separator is another, probably @.

For more information about dropping types:

Drop - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000945.html
Drop types - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.structypes.doc/doc/t0006611.html